# how can multiple layers be added to a end to end model?(combined end to end model with dense layer)

Tags: keras, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, lstm

I want to add one or more dense/cnn/lstm layers(sequential) to the beginning of the end to end model such as pytorch tabnet.
how can i?
in stacking ensemble , only the outputs are combined. But I want the tabnet to be in the continuation of the layers and both of them to be trained together seamlessly.
For example, in combining two layers lstm and cnn in a sequential model, we will have:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(n_feature,1), name='inputlayer'))
model.add(Conv1D(20, 1,activation="relu",padding="same"))
model.add(LSTM(2))
model.compile(loss= 'mean_squared_error' , optimizer= 'adam')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test,y_test))
```

But what about the end to end model such as below?

```
from pytorch_tabnet.tab_model import  TabNetRegressor
model= TabNetRegressor(n_d=23,
                  n_a=23,
                  gamma=1.2,
                  n_steps=4,
                  mask_type='entmax'
                        )
model.fit(
       X_train=X_train, y_train=y_train,
       eval_set=[(X_train, y_test), (X_valid, y_test)],
       eval_name=['train', 'test'],
       eval_metric=['rmsle', 'mae', 'rmse', 'mse'],
       patience=50,
       drop_last=False
       )
```

how can cnn or lstm or any layer be added to the beginning of tabnet model?

Comment: It can be done. You just write another network in pytorch(inherit from `nn.Module` class) and in the forward method call the forward of  `TabNetRegressor` after the layers you want to add. So this new model will have all the new layers and then the `TabNetRegressor` as well.

Comment: thanks a lot , Is there a similar code in this field to help me?

Comment: I saw this repository. `TabNetRegressor` is a not a `torch.nn.Module` class.  However it's just a wrapper around `TabNet` which is a `torch.nn.Module` class. So in your new module you can use `TabNet`.

Comment: Or there is a better much easier way. Use `TabNetEncoder` and inside it add an LSTM or CNN layer as you want. Then train like you are training right now.